# How to read an Access database column into an array with VB?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I apologize in advance if this has been answered before, but I couldn't seem to find exactly what I was looking for when I searched.

I'm not too familiar with VB. I was wondering if it was possible to read an entire column of a table in an Access database and put the data into an array using VB?

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are two different languages. Please specify the correct context

Comment: yes. it is also possible to read it into a dataset and leave right there in that easy to use container instead of making a copy of the data.

Comment: @Steve: Don't forget VB6 in that list, which is (remarkably) still being used for development of some legacy applications.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens but the question wasn't tagged VB6..

Comment: @Brad: If OP can't distinguish VB.NET from VBA, maybe he really means VB6. Who can tell without asking?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear but the answer provided below was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Access VBA you can use the `Recordset.GetRows` method.

This creates a two-dimensional array which matches the design of your recordset, and it takes a single parameter which is the number of rows to retrieve. To retrieve all rows, either get the `.RecordCount` before populating the array, or put in a number which you know is larger than required.

For example:

```
Sub ReadIntoArray()

    Dim rstName As Recordset
    Dim varName As Variant

    Set rstName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM tblContact")

    varName = rstFirstName.GetRows(1000) ' Gets the first 1000 records

    ' Retrieve the 16th value from the 1st column
    Debug.Print varName(0, 15)

    ' Get the 100th value from the 2nd column
    Debug.Print varName(1, 99)

End Sub
```

Comment: The Recordset would be the table I'm trying to pull the data from? I think this may exactly be what i'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: A recordset can be created in various ways to point to a table, a query, or a SQL statement (as in the example above). I suggest you look up 'OpenRecordset' on the Access help menu.