# How to read an Access database column into an array with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

[There's already a question like this but its in VBA, and I need VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920244/how-to-read-an-access-database-column-into-an-array-with-vb)

I'm trying to get the contents of a column then put them in an array or something so I can then put the data into the items of a ComboBox. If anyone can suggest a better way, id love to know. This is the code I am using right now:

```
sql = "SELECT Firstname FROM Candidates WHERE Position='President'"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: Your example is not complete - this wouldn't even get the data back from the database, much less convert a column of values into an array.

Comment: There are lots of examples around about getting data from a database using a data reader or a data adapter so you should read some of them. You've got a data reader. You should use it. Just keep in mind that you won't know how many records there are until you've read them, so you won't be able to actually create the array until you've read all the data unless you use `ReDim`, which you shouldn't.

Comment: Perhaps reading over some examples may help.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Answer (score 0):

So, first lets build the connection to the Access DB.

So, from the menu go project -> "my project name" properties
(last option).

This:

[image]

So, in above we hit the [...] button (connection builder).

Then this:

[image]

and then:

[image]

then use browse to select the Access database file.

If this is a "mdb" file, then we use JET, but for accDB, we have to choose/use
ACE.

So, after selecting the access file, then hit advanced:

this:

[image]

Now, it should default to ACE, but MAKE SURE you check this!!!

This:

[image]

If you don't see "ACE" in that list, then you not be able to use/open a accDB file, but can use JET to open mdb files.

Keep in mind, that if you are using vs2022?

Then the test connection button will ALWAYS fail, but if you run your project/code, it should work.

Note that you ALSO MUST force your project to x86 if you using/have Access x32 bits.

So, that is this option:

[image]

If you don't have/see a x86 option, then use the configeration manager, and create a x86 choice. You MUST do this!!

Ok, so now we have our connection built.

So, on a form, lets drop in a button to "load" the combo box, drop in a combo box.

And lets even drop in a button to show how to get/grab/use a value the user selected.

Now, a combo box can (often) have two columns. one column is "hidden", and the other is for display.

So, in our example, we will fill out the combo box with a list of hotels from the database, and we will use both columns.

"id"  - that is the database primary key value - it will be hidden, not display.

"HotelName" that is the column from the database to display in the combo box.

So, in the combo box property sheet, set:

ValueMember to ID
DisplayMember to HotelName (or your column to display).

So, the code for loading the combo box will look like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    cboHotels.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)

End Sub


Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

And our button code to test get/grab/see the selected value is this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Label2.Text = "Hotel Select = " & cboHotels.Text &
        "  value = " & cboHotels.SelectedValue


End Sub
```

Note how we are able to get the 2 values fro the combo box (the database primary key "value") and also the text (hotel name).

So, final result is this:

[image]

Comment: So where's the array that was the subject of the question?

Comment: In the question, the poster says this: "I'm trying to get the contents of a column then put them in an array or something". NOTE very close that part about "or something".

Comment: Actually, I missed the bit about the `ComboBox` in the question, so my apologies.